# Can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of the boolean parameter of the System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader, bool) method?

Tags: .net, xml, xmlreader

According to MSDN:
*defattr*
Type: [System.Boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx)
If **true**, copy the default attributes from the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx); otherwise **false**.If **true**, use default attributes; otherwise **false**.

And my question is what does the author mean by this?

Comment: I noticed this the other day. What's a default attribute? Why might I want to copy it?

Comment: ...er, those are the questions I asked myself when I read the same doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every xml element has a default attribute. Even if there is no attribute when you examine the raw xml, you will find that if you step thru any xml parser code when it uses a method like MoveToNextAttribute() there will  be an xmlns attribute whose value is a w3c uri(I dont recall the exact uri -something like xmlns='http://www.w3c.org/schema' You will also see it in the output from the ReadOuterXml() method for any element.

Comment: `xmlns` is not what they mean by "default attribute". See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

An XML Schema can define certain attributes as having default values. I think this is referring to those attributes - should they be returned, with their default values, when they are not explicitly specified?

---

I have confirmed this. I created the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ElementWithDefaultAttributes"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ElementWithDefaultAttributes.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ElementWithDefaultAttributes.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/ElementWithDefaultAttributes.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:complexType name="HasDefaultAttributesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Inner"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="default1" default="value1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="nodefault" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="default2" default="value2" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="HasDefaultAttributes" type="mstns:HasDefaultAttributesType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

I read the following document through an `XmlReader` configured with the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<HasDefaultAttributes xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ElementWithDefaultAttributes.xsd" 
   nodefault="none">
  <Inner>text</Inner>
</HasDefaultAttributes>
```

Despite this, when I used `XmlDictionaryWriter.WriteNode(reader, true)`, I got the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<HasDefaultAttributes nodefault="none" default1="value1" default2="value2" 
   xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ElementWithDefaultAttributes.xsd">
    <Inner>text</Inner>
</HasDefaultAttributes>
```

Code:

```
public static XDocument DefaultAttributes()
{
    var nt = new NameTable();
    var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet(nt);
    using (
        var schemaText =
            File.OpenText(
                @"..\..\XmlDictionaryWriter\ElementWithDefaultAttributes.xsd"))
    {
        var schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaText, ValidationEventHandler);
        schemas.Add(schema);
    }

    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                   {
                       ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
                       Schemas = schemas
                   };
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandler;

    using (
        var dataText =
            File.OpenText(
                @"..\..\XmlDictionaryWriter\HasDefaultAttributes.xml"))
    {
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (
                var xdw =
                    System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(
                        outputStream, Encoding.UTF8, false))
            {
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(dataText, settings))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        xdw.WriteNode(reader, true);
                    }
                }
            }

            outputStream.Position = 0;
            using (var output = new StreamReader(outputStream))
            {
                var doc = XDocument.Load(output);
                return doc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 (10 if i could) for the well thought out and tested answer. To bad the OP accepted the other answer without any verification.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that true will copy the attributes from the XmlReader, because of this function in the XmlReader class [GetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.getattribute%28VS.100%29.aspx) (When overridden in a derived class, gets the value of an attribute.)

EDIT:
An attribute is the date part (1st line)

```
<note date="12/11/2002">  
<to>Tove</to>   <from>Jani</from>  
<heading>Reminder</heading>  
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> </note>
```

Maybe the date doesn't get written automaticly. What about trying the the function with the boolean set to true and false. Maybe you can spot the differences and post here :)

Comment: Can you elaborate your reply a bit? I have to admit I did not grok it.

Comment: it means that It will not only copy the attributes explicitly specified, but also those with default values.